# Generate swagger model for generic parameter from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, nswag

I'm currently working on a project where we generate all our controllers automatically. Our BaseController has an action ike this:

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    public virtual Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ICreateEntityModel<TBaseEntity> model)
    {
        return ProcessActionAsync(model);
    }
```

After I setup NSwag I end up with models like this:

```
   ICreateEntityModelOfPerson:{  
     type:"object",
     x-abstract:true,
     additionalProperties:false
   }
```

The interface is just a marker and of no interest for an API user. Is there a way to generate the model for the actual type (in this case Person) and not the interface? Am I just missing the correct configuration or do I need an extra processor?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ProducesResponseType(200, typeof(...)]` to specify the response type for a given status code.

Answer (score 0):

[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorMessage), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

works for me